# Подскажите где копать про ListView с красиво убирающимися заголовками

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

У меня в лист выводятся фотографии над каждой фотографией есть маленькая панелька растянутая на всю ширину экрана, и я бо хотел чтобы при скроллинге фотографий вниз эта панелька не уходила за верхнюю границу экрана пока ее не выдавит следующая панелька следующей фотографии (подобно инстаграмму, если кто замечал)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Копать в сторону CollectionViewSource с группировкой.